# Do pages of application executable code get swapped out?

Tags: memory-management, paging

Is there anyone know: 
Do pages of application executable code get swapped out?

I know kernel code never been swapped out to disk. Not sure about the static code of application.

If the answer is yes, how can I make this swapping happen? I have checked some applications in my computer, I didn't see any pages of the application executable code have been swapped out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Paging is a technique used to manage memory.  Generally speaking, yes; anything that could be in RAM could be paged.  Why don't you check out [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Demand_paging), which is pretty well-written.